# Имя переменной, переданной в функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

Можно ли как-то узнать имя переменной, которую передали в функцию:

```
def f(x):
    ...

y = 1
z = 2
f(y) # напеччатет y
f(z) # напеччатет z
```

Comment: В функцию передается не переменная, а.ее значение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, хорошо. Можно ли узнать имя перменной, значение которой передано в функцию?

Comment: Как вы думаете, 5 - это значение какой переменной?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, может есть какие-нибудь косвенные методы как это сделать? В python'e ведь можно с ast работать, получать все локальные и глобальные переменные. Менять код во время выполнения. Может как-то можно узнать строку с кодом когда функция вызывалась распарсить её и получить имя переменной. Или ещё как-нибудь.

Comment: @pank, `ast` вам тут не помощник - функция изнутри не знает, откуда ее вызвали и кто это сделал. Да и зачем бы ей это нужно было знать? Любые решения - это всякие извращения и грабли. Ваша задача имеет какое-то практическое применение (тогда стоит озвучить конечную цель?) или суть исследование?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How can you print a variable name in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/592746/4279)

Comment: @m9_psy, не думаю, что можно тут можно придумать какое-нибудь практическое применение. Этот вопрос, возможно, поможет лучше понять язык.

Comment: @pank: "практическое" применение: (а) [эмуляция `f""` literals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13312240/4279) из Python 3.6 на более ранних версиях (б) [информативные сообщения об ошибке в парсере](https://goo.gl/anjzMt), без явной передачи контекста каждый раз.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это можно сделать в CPython, но не рекомендуется -- в зависимости от вашей конкретной задачи, могут более удачные решения существовать, чем пытаться имя объекта из вызываемого окружения определить:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def f(x):
...     caller_locals = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
...     print(*[name for name, value in caller_locals.items() if x is value])
>>> y = 1
>>> z = 2
>>> f(y)
y    
>>> f(z)
z
```

---

В зависимости от того как REPL реализована, можно различить `f(y)` от `f(z)` вызовы, даже если `y = z = 1`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> import inspect
>>> def f(x):
...     caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
...     dis.dis(caller_frame.f_code)
... 
>>> y = z = 1
>>> f(y)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (f)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 PRINT_EXPR
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> f(z)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (f)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (z)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 PRINT_EXPR
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> f(1)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (f)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 PRINT_EXPR
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Имя переданной переменной присутствует в байт-коде вызывающего frame. Программно можно найти вызов функции (`CALL_FUNCTION`  инструкция) и посмотреть какое именно имя передано (если вообще имя было использовано) из `caller_frame.f_code.co_names` списка. К примеру в CPython 2:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import byteplay  # $ pip install byteplay
>>> def f(x):
...     bc = byteplay.Code.from_code(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code)
...     i = next(i for i, (opcode, _) in enumerate(bc.code) if opcode == byteplay.CALL_FUNCTION)
...     print bc.code[i-1][1]
... 
>>> y = z = 1
>>> f(y)
y
>>> f(z)
z
>>> f(1)
1
```

Disclaimer: ответ для образовательных целей, не для использования в рабочем коде.

Comment: Опять проблема если y = z = 1.

Comment: @pank: именно поэтому код использует список, а не возвращается когда найдено только одно имя. Попробуйте. `f(1)` напечатает оба имени (обратите внимание, я передал `1`, а напечатается `y z`).  Кроме реализации REPL, никому эти имена неизвестны (если не пытаться содержимое экрана читать (и тому подобное)). В любом случае какой бы грязный хак эту информацию не получал, в зависимости от конкретной задачи, должны быть более разумные варианты нежели имена пытаться определить.

Comment: можете кратко описать как работает ваш код?

Comment: @pank не хочу поощрять подобные хаки, но кратко: 1- находим текущее положение стека вызовов (currentframe()) 2- берём предыдущий frame (f_backs), откуда функция была вызвана 3- берём локальные переменные для вызывающего кода (f_locals) в виде словаря 4-  перебираем все локальные переменные, печатаем те имена, которые ссылаются на переданный объект.

Comment: что такое frame?

Comment: @pank: это то что в стек вызовов кладут при каждом вызове. [Терминология из C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure). Исполнение кода в текущем frame, это [основная работа СPython интерпретатора](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html?highlight=pyframeobject#c.PyEval_EvalFrameEx). Что такое frame в С или CPython можно в виде отдельного вопроса задать.

Answer (score 2):

можно грязным хаком :)

```
def f(x, g=globals()):
    print([n for n in g if id(g[n]) == id(x)])

y = 1
z = 2
f(y) # напеччатет y
f(z) # напеччатет z

>>> ['y']
>>> ['z']
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает, если y = z = 1

Comment: Но отлично работает, если переданная переменная является уникальным объектом.

Comment: `id(a) == id(b)` можно на `a is b` заменить, [см. namestr()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/592891/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Я как-то нашёл это решение на каком-то сайте заморском. Там говорили, что оно нестабильно, и это действительно было так. Но я более менее разобрался в нём и даже немного модифицировал, но до сих пор считаю это магией и не до конца понимаю как это работает. Единственное что, попробовал я сейчас сделать декораторы и запросить имя переменной через них. К сожалению, результат совсем не тот. И дело в том, что строка при вызове декораторов не показывает ничего, кроме названия самой функции в ней

```
import traceback
import re

def get_name(__x, level=0): # 0 - global, 1 - local, может быть есть и 2...
    name = traceback.extract_stack()[level][3]
    name = re.sub(r'.*get_name\(', '', name)
    name = re.search(r'[^,|()]*', name).group(0)
    return name

def foo(level=1):
    a = 2
    var_1 = 4
    print(get_name(a, level))
    print(get_name(var_1, level))

def goo():
    foo()

def dec():
    goo()

a = 1
b = 3
var1 = 2
var2 = 4

print(get_name(a))
print(get_name(b))
print(get_name(var1))
print(get_name(var2))

dec() # goo() - после преобразования - goo
goo() # foo() - после преобразования - foo
foo() # а тут уже внутри переменные
```

Comment: Как я понял, `traceback.extract_stack()[level][3]` - возвращает строку где вызывалась функция. Решение не универсальное, например, не работает в repl.it и в jupyer'e.

Comment: @pank ну ничего другого предложить не могу. У вас есть решение?

Comment: нет. Если найду что-нибудь добавлю сюда.

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно так:

```
print([name for name, value in locals().items() if value is x])
```

Правда, как и в примерах выше, при x = y = 1 вернет `['x', 'y']`