# Название словаря в Python

Tags: python

**Задача из учебника:**

> Домашние животные: создайте несколько словарей, имена которых
>   представляют клички домашних животных. В каждом словаре сохраните
>   информацию о виде животного и имени владельца. Сохраните словари в списке с именем pets. Переберите элементы списка. В процессе перебора выведите всю имеющуюся информацию о каждом животном.

Я написал вот такой код

```
tom = {'cat': 'boy'}
jerry = {'mouse': 'girl'}
pets = [tom, jerry]
for pet in pets:
    for animal in pet.keys():
        print("Animal: " + animal.title())
    for owner in pet.values():
        print("Owner: " + owner.title() + '\n')
```

Вопрос: как вывести клички?

Comment: Никак, ведь у вас в словарях нет кличек.

Comment: Непонятно тогда, зачем специально указали назвать словари кличками. Ведь если просят вывести всю имеющуюся информацию, предполагается, что и клички тоже должны быть указаны. А раз это невозможно, остаётся неопределённость.

Comment: все, что можно, уже выведено

Comment: если очень хочется, то словарь словарей сделайте (клички как ключи). В сторону раскапывания имён словарей (в globals()) не стоит углубляться.

Comment: @USSeR, логичнее было бы сделать как-то так: `tom = {'name': 'tom', 'kind': 'cat', 'sex': 'male'}`. Имена переменных не являются данными (как правило).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Имя переменной, переданной в функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/652467/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Я сделал это упражнение следующим образом:

```
pet_0 = {'nickname' : 'Barsik', 'type' : 'Cat', 'owner' : 'Misha'}
pet_1 = {'nickname' : 'Gari', 'type' : 'dog', 'owner' : 'Alina'}
pet_2 = {'nickname' : 'Jeri', 'type' : 'mouse', 'owner' : 'Vasya'}

pets = [pet_0, pet_1, pet_2]

for pet in pets:
    for k, v in pet.items():
       print(k + ' : ' + v)
```