# можно ли получить имя переменной экземпляра класса внутри __init__ этого же экземпляра?

Tags: python, ооп

Ну то есть

```
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head:Node = None):
        self.head = head
        self.name = self.какая-то_магия_дающая_имя_self
```

Да, извращение. Если интересно - просто хочу реализовать связанный список и классически, и через словари и через списки и, конкретно здесь, через SQLite. Ну и хочу хранить в базе в оьдельном поле имя списка, которому принадлежат узлы...
такая себе автосериализация будет...

Пример в предложенном возможном дубле вопроса insolor, не работает:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,value, g=globals()):
        self. value = value
        print(*[n for n in g if g[n] is self])

dd = Test(33)
print(dd.value)
```

на печать выдает только 33. Если при уже существующем dd запустить

```
Test.__init__(dd,34)
```

то `dd` распечатается...
Похоже - никак?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101558/discussion-on-question-by-vasyl-kolomiets------).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Имя переменной, переданной в функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652467/Имя-переменной-переданной-в-функцию)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение в байткоде:

```
class Test1():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self. value = value
        caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        dis.dis(caller_frame.f_code)
        text = dis.Bytecode(caller_frame.f_code)
        for text in text:
            if "STORE_NAME" in text: 
                print ( f' имя переменной:  {text.argrepr}' )

victory = Test1(33)
```

выдаст на печать:

```
 12           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (Test1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (33)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (victory)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
 имя переменной:  victory
```

хотя это все не годится, например, для работы в цикле и присвоению элементам списка...
придется передавать имя явно. Ну или еще что о придумаю.

Answer (score 0):

`когда мы пишем lst = LinkedList(object), то срабатывает __init__(self, head:Node = None) с lst вместо self. Ну вот lst - это и есть имя экземпляра класса – Vasyl Kolomiets`

Все гораздо проще - автор читает это слева направо, а не справа налево
`lst = LinkedList(object)`

Т.е. считает что сначала происходит присваивание `lst =` и затем это имя передается в **init** где потом создается объект - конечно это неверно

На самом же деле - Сначала создается объект, который на этом этапе никуда не сохраняется

1) `LinkedList(object)`

и только потом то, что там создано сохраняется в lst,

2) `lst = то что мы создали ранее`

т.е. имя переменной известно только После создания объекта, но никак не до его создания

Конечно правильнее передавать эти имена явно, аргументом или использовать один контейнер(напр dict) для хранения всех экземпляров, а идея автора делать как он описал - плоха